# Does Fabric have a function to encrypt a blockfile?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to encrypt a blockfile (under `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgerData/chains/chains/mychannel` by default) because `value`is clear text and we can see it by `cat` or `less` command.

Does Fabric have a function to encrypt a blockfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in option to encrypt blocks or data in blocks.
You have two options:

1. Encrypt the filesystem - this is the most common option ... mount an encrypted filesystem and use that to store the ledger.
2. Add encryption within your chaincode - you can add custom logic in your chaincode to encrypt/decrypt kyes/values.  This can get fairly complicated though.

Option 1 is the most common for production systems